# How do I pass XML data as a PAYLOAD on the stream?

Tags: php, xml, parameter-passing

I'm new to XML, and usually use JSON to pass data. I am working with a new system, and this was part of their instructions to me about passing data:

> The XML content then can be sent as either PAYLOAD on the stream or as an additional parameter.  If the latter is done, the parameter name is RequestXML

I'm not sure what this means? I'm afraid if I pass it as a parameter, but I have a lot of text, it will make the URL too long, so I'd like to do the PAYLOAD option. I'm using PHP and Jquery to generate the array. I can create an XML file using PHP and have it properly formatted as XML, but sending it across is confusing me.

What do I need to do to get it sent as a PAYLOAD?

Comment: what is the **system** ??

Comment: It's a system written in Java I believe. Warehouse Management System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely just want to send a POST HTTP request.  Here's an example using the curl library:

```
<?php
$url = "https://example.com/service";
$xml = "<foo />";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Had to test it, sorry for the late reply. This worked just fine.